# Polymorphism and Interfaces in C#

Tags: c#

Create three small classes unrelated by inheritance—classes Building, Car and Bicycle. Write an interface ICarbonFootprint with a GetCarbonFootprint method. Have each of your classes implement that interface, so that its GetCarbonFootprint method calculates an appropriate carbon footprint for that class (check out a few websites that explain how to calculate carbon footprints). Write an app that creates objects of each of the three classes, places references to those objects in List, then iterates through the List, polymorphically invoking each object’s GetCarbonFootprint method. Constructor of Car initialize “gallon of gas”, and the Building constructor will initialize buiding-square-footage.

how to calculate carbon-footprint

One gallon of gas yields 20 pounds of CO2 for a car

Multiply the square footage by 50 for a building

None for a bicycle

My instructor's code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ICarbonFootprint[] list = new ICarbonFootprint[3];

            // add elements to list
            list[0] = new Bicycle();
            list[1] = new Building(2500);
            list[2] = new Car(10);

            // display carbon footprint of each object
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
                list[i].GetCarbonFootprint();
        } // end Main
    }
```

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Miller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Bicycle bike = new Bicycle();
            Building b = new Building();
            Car car = new Car();

            List<ICarbonFootprint> list = new List<ICarbonFootprint>();


            list.Add(bike);
            list.Add(b);
            list.Add(car);

            int totalCarbon = 0;

            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                totalCarbon += item.GetCarbonFootprint();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has a footprint of: {1}", item,      item.GetCarbonFootprint());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Total footprint is: {0}", totalCarbon);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }


    public class Bicycle : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;

        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set { _make = value; }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 10;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Bike");
        }
    }

    public class Building : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private string _address;

        public string Address
        {
            get { return _address; }
            set { _address = value; }
        }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 2000;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Building");
        }
    }

    public class Car : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;


        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set { _make = value; }
        }
        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 1500;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Car");
        }
    }

    public interface ICarbonFootprint
    {
        int GetCarbonFootprint();



    }


}
```

Me integrating my instructor's code (lines 12-23 changed AKA class Program was the only thing changed):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Miller
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ICarbonFootprint[] list = new ICarbonFootprint[3];

            // add elements to list
            list[0] = new Bicycle();
            list[1] = new Building(2500);
            list[2] = new Car(10);

            // display carbon footprint of each object
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
                list[i].GetCarbonFootprint();
        } // end Main
    }

    public class Bicycle : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;

        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set { _make = value; }
        }

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 10;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Bike");
        }
    }

    public class Building : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private string _address;

        public string Address
        {
            get { return _address; }
            set { _address = value; }
        }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 2000;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Building");
        }
    }

    public class Car : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private string _make;
        private string _model;


        public string Make
        {
            get { return _make; }
            set { _make = value; }
        }
        public string Model
        {
            get { return _model; }
            set { _model = value; }
        }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 1500;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("Car");
        }
    }

    public interface ICarbonFootprint
    {
        int GetCarbonFootprint();



    }


}
```

So, replacing my code for class Program with my instructor's code, I received the following errors:

```
Program.cs(51,23,51,41): error CS1729: 'Miller.Building' does not contain a         constructor that takes 1 arguments
Program.cs(52,23,52,34): error CS1729: 'Miller.Car' does not contain a   constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

Now, because the last two days before Spring break were cancelled due to the weather (snow), we weren't able to discuss. My code seems to do what the directions ask, but I would like to get my instructor's code for class Program working with my code. Could someone help me with these errors possibly?

Comment: Your error simply says `'Miller.Building' does not contain a         constructor that takes 1 arguments`, means `Building` doesn't have any constructor that takes 1 argument, you must be missing some part of code.

Comment: u r missing this part of the questions: "*Constructor of Car initialize “gallon of gas”, and the Building constructor will initialize buiding-square-footage.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.

First up you need to include the constructors to make the code compile.

For `Building` this would look like:

```
    private int squareFootage;
    public Building(int squareFootage)
    {
        this.squareFootage = squareFootage;
    }
```

And for `Car` this would look like:

```
    private int gasGallons;
    public Car(int gasGallons)
    {
        this.gasGallons = gasGallons;
    }
```

Next, you're not following the rules for calculating the carbon footprint.

They should be:

```
    //Bicycle
    public int GetCarbonFootprint()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    //Building
    public int GetCarbonFootprint()
    {
        return 50 * squareFootage;
    }

    //Car
    public int GetCarbonFootprint()
    {
        return 20 * gasGallons;
    }
```

Finally, your instructor's code doesn't actually display any results. The code in the for loop should be changed to be `Console.WriteLine(list[i].GetCarbonFootprint());` if this is a console app.

So, all up the code should look like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ICarbonFootprint[] list = new ICarbonFootprint[3];

    // add elements to list
    list[0] = new Bicycle();
    list[1] = new Building(2500);
    list[2] = new Car(10);

    // display carbon footprint of each object
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(list[i].GetCarbonFootprint());
}

    public class Bicycle : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public class Building : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private int squareFootage;
        public Building(int squareFootage)
        {
            this.squareFootage = squareFootage;
        }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 50 * squareFootage;
        }
    }

    public class Car : ICarbonFootprint
    {
        private int gasGallons;
        public Car(int gasGallons)
        {
            this.gasGallons = gasGallons;
        }

        public string Make { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }

        public int GetCarbonFootprint()
        {
            return 20 * gasGallons;
        }
    }

    public interface ICarbonFootprint
    {
        int GetCarbonFootprint();
    }
```

I've opted to short-cut the property definitions rather than implement them with fields.

The output is:

```
0
125000
200
```

Comment: Output: 0, 125000, 200

Comment: Also, I had to use public static void Main(string[] args) or static void Main(string[] args) rather than void Main() alone

Comment: Enigmativity, does 0, 125000, 200 sound reasonable

Comment: And is it more proper to use  public static void Main(string[] args) or static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: @Nestle - I fixed the `Main` signature - I use LINQPad for coding my answers and forgot to fix the signature when I copy and pasted. I also added the output to my answer. I think it is best to be explicit and use the `public` modifier.

Answer (score 0):

You should write constructors for Building and Car like next:

```
public Building(int MyValue)
{
...
}
```

and your code will work fine.

Comment: it will build yes, but will not fulfill the requirements.

Answer (score -2):

Suggestion: Car and Bicycle shares properties, and the `ICarbonFootprint` implementation, so you can create a base class with an abstract method. Also the `GetCarbonFootprint` from `ICarbonFootprint` interface must be type of `System.Double`.

```
public interface ICarbonFootprint
{
    int GetCarbonFootprint();
}

public class Building : ICarbonFootprint
{
    public int BuildingSquareFootage { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public Building(int buildingSquareFootage, string address)
    {
        BuildingSquareFootage = buildingSquareFootage;
        Address = address;
    }

    public int GetCarbonFootprint()
    {
        return BuildingSquareFootage * 50;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Building");
    }
}

public abstract class CarBicycleBase : ICarbonFootprint
{
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    protected CarBicycleBase(string make, string model)
    {
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
    }
    public abstract int GetCarbonFootprint();
}

public class Bicycle : CarBicycleBase
{
    public Bicycle(string make, string model)
        : base(make, model) { }

    public override int GetCarbonFootprint()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Bike");
    }
}

public class Car : CarBicycleBase
{
    public int GallonOfGas { get; set; }

    public Car(int gallonOfGas, string make, string model)
        : base(make, model)
    {
        GallonOfGas = gallonOfGas;
    }

    public override int GetCarbonFootprint()
    {
        return GallonOfGas * 20;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Car");
    }
}
```

Example:

```
...
var list = new List<ICarbonFootprint>(3)
{
    new Car(10, "...", "..."),
    new Bicycle("...", "..."),
    new Building(20, "...")
};

foreach (ICarbonFootprint item in list)
    item.GetCarbonFootprint();
...
```

I hope it helps.